# How to translate this code in python to be more readable?

Tags: python, refactoring, translate

I want to translate this code to be more readable but when I tried, it does not work. It works in the original version, but don't work in the second one.

I tried in this way.

```
down, up = [(+1, -1), (+1, +1)], [(-1, -1), (-1, +1)]
length = board.get_length()
piece = board.get(row, col)
if piece:
    for (x, y) in down:
        if (0 <= (row + x) < length) and (0 <= (col + y) < length) and board.is_free(row + x, col + y):
            bottom = [main.deindexify(row + x, col + y)]

    # bottom = [main.deindexify(row + x, col + y) for (x, y) in down \
    #           if (0 <= (row + x) < length)
    #           and (0 <= (col + y) < length) \
    #           and board.is_free(row + x, col + y)]

    for (x, y) in up:
        if (0 <= (row + x) < length) and (0 <= (col + y) < length) and board.is_free(row + x, col + y):
            top = [main.deindexify(row + x, col + y)]

    # top = [main.deindexify(row + x, col + y) for (x, y) in up \
    #        if (0 <= (row + x) < length) \
    #        and (0 <= (col + y) < length) \
    #        and board.is_free(row + x, col + y)]

            if piece.is_king():
        return sorted(bottom + top)
    else:
        if piece.is_black():
            return sorted(bottom)
        else:
            if is_sorted:
                return sorted(top)
            else:
                if piece.is_king():
                    return bottom + top
                else:
                    if piece.is_black():
                        return bottom
                    else:
                        return top

    # return (sorted(bottom + top) if piece.is_king() else \
    #             (sorted(bottom) if piece.is_black() else sorted(top))) \
    #     if is_sorted else (bottom + top if piece.is_king() else \
    #                            (bottom if piece.is_black() else top))
return []
```

And this is an error:

```
line 61, in get_moves
return sorted(bottom)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bottom' referenced before assignment
```

This is the original version.

```
 down, up = [(+1, -1), (+1, +1)], [(-1, -1), (-1, +1)]
length = board.get_length()
piece = board.get(row, col)
if piece:
    bottom = [main.deindexify(row + x, col + y) for (x, y) in down \
              if (0 <= (row + x) < length) \
              and (0 <= (col + y) < length) \
              and board.is_free(row + x, col + y)]
    top = [main.deindexify(row + x, col + y) for (x, y) in up \
           if (0 <= (row + x) < length) \
           and (0 <= (col + y) < length) \
           and board.is_free(row + x, col + y)]
    return (sorted(bottom + top) if piece.is_king() else \
                (sorted(bottom) if piece.is_black() else sorted(top))) \
        if is_sorted else (bottom + top if piece.is_king() else \
                               (bottom if piece.is_black() else top))
return []
```

Can someone explain me how to read this code and to translate it, so I can refactorise rest of the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: In the first example, the indentation seems wrong in a couple of places ( either logically or syntactically ).  Maybe post on codereview.stackexchange.com to get feedback on your code and ways to improve?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better to ask it on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: What is it exactly then? If it is some kind of test I'd prefer not to give you the answer.

Comment: It is a project for school. We had to find a template, then understand and modify it, so I'm doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of the code (from the original) creates a list if `x` and `y` meet certain conditions. It is written as a list comprehension.

```
....
    bottom = [main.deindexify(row + x, col + y) for (x, y) in down \
              if (0 <= (row + x) < length) \
              and (0 <= (col + y) < length) \
              and board.is_free(row + x, col + y)]
```

One way to *unwind* the list comprehension (refactor) into a `for` loop might be:

```
....
    bottom = []
    for (x,y) in down:
        x_length = (0 <= (row + x) < length)
        y_length = (0 <= (col + y) < length)
        cel_isfree = board.is_free(row + x, col + y)
        if x_length and ylength and cel_isfree:
            bottom.append(main.deindexify(row + x, col + y))
```

`top` could also be refactored this way.

The following piece of the original code determines the return value based on a couple of conditions - the type of *piece*, and whether or not to sort. It is written as a nested [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

```
....
    return (sorted(bottom + top) if piece.is_king() else \
                (sorted(bottom) if piece.is_black() else sorted(top))) \
        if is_sorted else (bottom + top if piece.is_king() else \
                               (bottom if piece.is_black() else top))
```

It can be refactored like this:

```
....
    if is_sorted:
        if piece.is_king():
            return_value = sorted(bottom + top)
        elif piece.is_black():
            return_value = sorted(bottom)
        else:
            return_value = sorted(top)
    else:
        if piece.is_king():
            return_value = bottom + top
        elif piece.is_black():
            return_value = bottom
        else:
            return_value = top
    return return_value
```

---

Of course I don't have an easy way to test this.